# How to include smarty script with mosaico email

Tags: mosaico, smarty

I used to use a name personalisation in civimail with smarty script...

```
{capture assign=nickname}{contact.nick_name}{/capture} Dear {if $nickname}{contact.nick_name}{else}{contact.sort_name}{/if}
```

I was testing if this script would render in mosaico 2.x, it seems doesn't work. Is there any workaround? Thanks

Comment: Have you turned on SMARTY in civicrm.settings.php?

Comment: Smarty can be turned on. It won't help with mosaico.

Comment: yes, its turned on , and I was using with civimail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround for the specific example in your post, you can create a custom token.  [This post](https://civicrm.org/blog/colemanw/create-your-own-tokens-for-fun-and-profit) explains how using [hook_civicrm_tokens](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_tokens/) and [hook_civicrm_tokenValues](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_tokenValues/)

Comment: Thanks. That’s how we have achieved our goal.

Answer (score 2):

I looked into it a while back. Seems mosaico is not compatible with smarty.

Comment: Thanks, is there a workaround?

Comment: Not afaik. Would live to hear of one if you do find.